# Select events having different probabilities - C++

Tags: c++, random

I have to run a simulation where each event E_i has a certain probability P_i to happen (i=1..4, sum_i P_i = 1).

I would like to write a function that, taken as input the four different probabilities (they depend on other things happening in my simulation), returns the integer i for the chosen event.

Which is the best way to write such a function (possibly only using standard libraries,
I have to run it on a cluster where I don't own the permissions to add new libraries)?.

I was thinking to write something like:

```
int get_event(double p1,double p2, double p3, double p4){
    double r=((double) rand())/(RAND_MAX); // alternatively here there can be any function that
    // generates a random number uniformly distribute in (0,1);
    if (r<=p1) return 1;
    else if (r>p1 && r <=(p1+p2)) return 2;
    else if (r>(p1+p2) && r <=(p1+p2+p3)) return 3;
    else if (r>(p1+p2+p3) && r <=1) return 4;
    else return -1; // -1 is an en error code;
}
```

but I am not sure if this is the best approach. Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty good, I'd suggest only a few small changes:

```
int get_event(double p1,double p2, double p3, double p4){
    double r=((double) rand())/(RAND_MAX);
    if (r<=p1) return 1;
    r-= p1;
    if (r<=p2) return 2;
    r-= p2;
    if (r<=p3) return 3;
    r-= p3;
    if (r<=p4) return 4;
    return -1; // -1 is an en error code;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems a pretty elegant solution!

Comment: Is accumulated error over multiple sequential subtractions going to be come an issue?

Answer (score 3):

There is a method that works in O(1) time.

http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/

http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/04/04/simulating-a-loaded-dice-in-a-constant-time

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how you can generalize your code while making it work for larger number of probabilities. Also I have included eps to the comparison.

```
const double eps = 1e-9;
int get_event(double p[], int psize){
    double r=rand()/(RAND_MAX); // alternatively here there can be any function that
    // generates a random number uniformly distribute in (0,1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= psize; ++i) {
      r -= p[i-1];
      if (r < eps) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1; // -1 is an en error code;
}
```

Comment: just one small comment, rand returns an int so the result needs to be casted before dividing by RAND_MAX. This is common to all the implementations posted so far!

Comment: @LucaCerone actually my code is based on yours. I did not modify the part generating the random number itself.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed later my mistake :) it was just a warning for who searches for answers :)